# Write to two database refs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase web app serving as a registration system. When a user registers for a course, the course data is added to their list of all registrations as part of the callback function. When the user registers, the newest class is duplicated in the list. On a page load, each course is only listed once.

**Realtime Database Structure**

```
{
  courses: {
    courseIdA: {
      // course data
    },
    couseIdB ... {}
  },
  users: {
    uid: {
      regs: {
        courseIdA: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a user registers, they are added to both the course ID as a `member object` and to their `users` object under their `uid`. The callback fires twice because I'm writing to the `courses` ref *and* the `users` ref. Is there a way to write to both simultaneously? Or do I need to come up with a better structure for the database?

**Get classes, listen for changes**

```js
PDReg.prototype.getAllClasses = function() {
  this.database = firebase.database()
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var courses = [];
  var today = new Date().toISOString();

  this.classesRef = this.database.ref('courses');
  this.userRef = this.database.ref('users/' + uid + "/regs");

    var setClass = function(snapshot) {
      var course = snapshot.val();
      course.key = snapshot.key;

      // check for the current user in a course
      if(course.members) {

        if(course.members.hasOwnProperty(uid)) {

          // This callback fires twice when someone registers
          this.buildUserClasses(course);
        } else {
          this.buildAllClasses(course)
        }
      } else {
        this.buildAllClasses(course)
      }
    }.bind(this);

    // listen for changes to the classes database, rebuild the UI
    this.classesRef.orderByChild('start').startAt(today).on('child_added', setClass);
    this.classesRef.on('child_changed', setClass);
};
```

**Register**

```js
PDReg.prototype.register = function(e) {
  // It's a form submit, don't reload the page
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this.courseForm;
  var classes = [];
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  for (var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
    // build the object to submit and add to an array
  }

  for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
    this.coursesRef = this.database.ref('courses/' + classes[i].id + '/members/' + uid);

    // Write the member object to `courses` under the correct key
    this.coursesRef.set({'code': classes[i]['code']}).then(function(classes) {
    // write to the user ref
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/regs/' + id).set(true);
    onSuccess(title);
document.getElementById('allCourses').removeChild(document.getElementById(id))
    }, function(e) {
      onFailure(e, title);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: No matter how you write (even if you did a multi-location update), if you have two listeners on two locations, and those two locations get written, you will trigger two callbacks.  Perhaps you should have different callbacks for each location instead that don't duplicate work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't think I really have a good understanding of `child_added` vs `child_changed`. If I comment out `child_added`, nothing loads on a refresh. If I comment `child_changed`, courses aren't added to the list when a user registers. Should I break out the `setClass` method into it's own function?

Comment: If they need to do different things, I'd make them different functions.